# Confused about Subjunctive tense with que and certainty

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo, indicativo

So, I was working on some Spanish work and I found something that I'm not sure about.

The sentence I'm writing says:

> No sé qué quiero ser en el futuro.

So this is where I get confused. I know that when you use que, not as what but as in that or than or the other meanings, you would use the subjunctive tense after, like this:

> No sé que quiera ser algo en el futuro.

But in my case, I'm using "qué" as in what. However, there is still the uncertainty. "I don't know." I'm not sure if the whole object of the verb saber would be "qué quiero ser" or if I need the subjunctive tense. It might also be that putting the subjunctive tense would make it translate like, "I don't know what I may want to be" changing the I want to have the uncertainty. So if anyone has insight, let me know.

Comment: There is a typo in your sentences, "futuro" is "masculine" (not sure if that's the right word in English). It should be "el futuro". Apart of that for me the first sentence is correct, no need of subjunctive there.

Comment: @RubioRic indeed in English we refer to the grammatical genders as masculine and feminine.

Comment: @mdewey Thanks! :-)

Comment: Somehow, I think you are missing lo.

Answer (score 2):

The verb *saber* is not a verb of uncertainty, and is not included in the several online lists of verbs that require subjunctive (e.g. [1](http://uni.canuelo.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/subjuntivo_formas_y_usos_nvo.pdf), [2](https://espanol.lingolia.com/es/gramatica/tiempos-subjuntivo/verbos). The official *Nueva Gramática de la Lengua Española* seems to be down or gone from the Internet). This means that the direct object of *saber* (i.e., what is or isn't known) generally does **not** use subjunctive.

Your example with "que"

> *No sé que quiera ser algo en el futuro.

is a contradiction, because you cannot say "No sé que" followed by a statement. Saying the statement means that you know it, but then you say you don't know it. It is like saying "I don't know that his car is red" (or "I don't know that I want to become something in the future"): it is a contradiction.

If you change to the third person, then you do not have a contradiction, but you need to use the **indicative**, because there is no uncertainty. There is a fact, and a person that does not know that fact:

- Él no sabe que **quiero** ser algo en el futuro.
- Él no sabe que mi coche **es** rojo.

To make *saber* express an uncertainty, it needs to be followed by an actual reported question. A reported question either begins with "si" (if it is a yes/no question), or it begins with an interrogative pronoun. This is the same structure as in English and also uses the indicative:

- No sé **si quiero** ser algo en el futuro (*I don't know **if** I want to become something in the future*)
- No sé **qué quiero** ser en el futuro (*I don't know **what** I want to become in the future*).

Comment: La idea va por ahí, pero NO es cierto que **saber** nunca use el subjuntivo. Si fuera así, no existirían las conjugaciones de subjuntivo para tal verbo, cuando éstas existen para la mayoría de los verbos, incluyendo a *saber*.  Pero lo que dijiste está cerca de ser *la* respuesta. Yo aún tengo que pensar mi respuesta, a menos que alguien que **sepa** me anticipe y responda bien

Comment: La pregunta creo que refiere a por qué es que **quiero** está en indicativo. Por último, sí que es posible combinar el verbo saber con ambos que/qué (relativo/interrogativo) aunque sea más común hacerlo con el segundo; pero no veo que esté relacionado con la pregunta

Comment: "No sé si quiera" es también válida. También lo es "No sé si quiero" y "No sé si quisiese/era".

Comment: @tac me refiero a que el **complemento directo** de *saber* generalmente no usa el subjuntivo. Obviamente, "saber" puede ir en subjuntivo, y frases con "saber" pueden tener otros verbos en subjuntivo. Pero "lo que se sabe" suele ir en indicativo.

Comment: @DanielCastro al menos en mi dialecto, me suena muy raro "no sé si quiera" o "no sé si quisiese". Quizá en otros es más común...

Comment: @DanielCastro A mí también me suena raro.

Comment: @RubioRic (CC wimi) ‘no sé si quisiera’ es una construcción súper común. Por ejemplo, puede usarse para bajarle el tono a la otra alternativa más directa: ‘de ninguna manera lo haría’

Comment: @wimi Además, ‘que [that]’ no contradice a ’no sé’ [don't know]’. El problema simplemente es que no concuerdan, pero sin embargo es posible lograr la concordancia con verbos similares: ‘—¿Pueden haber chanchos voladores? — **no conozco que** exista algo como eso’. ¿Están en contradicción ‘que’ y ‘no conozco’? No lo creo

Comment: @tac parece que el problema es solo con "saber". Yo nunca diría "no sé que existan", pero quizá sí "no me consta que existan". En inglés lo mismo: no se dice "I don't know that they exist" pero sí se dice "I am not aware that they exist". La razón no la sé.

Comment: @tac yo creo que "no sé si quisiera" no se dice en España. En todo caso "no sé si querría". Tengo entendido que el subjuntivo se usa más en Latinoamérica. Corríjame algún español si me equivoco, que puede ser.

Answer (score 1):

**¿Cuál es tu definición de duda [uncertainty]?**

No puedo pensar en una regla que funcione en todas las situaciones. Básicamente, la duda se *siente* y no creo que sea posible trazar un límite claro entre el ‘ámbito de lo subjuntivo’ y el ‘ámbito de lo indicativo’. Dicho esto, frases como:

> - No **sé** qué **quiero** ser en el futuro.
> - No **sé** si **quiero** ser algo en el futuro.
> - No **sabía** que eso era cierto.

No pertenecen a lo subjuntivo, porque afirmás con total convicción tu carencia de conocimiento. No estás dudando sobre si sabés o no sabés.  Incluso, cuando decís ‘yo dudo’ estás afirmando que dudás con total convicción. No estás dudando sobre tu dudar, por lo tanto en este caso tampoco tiene sentido usar el subjuntivo.

Algunas situaciones del ámbito de lo subjuntivo podrían ser:

> - No creo que **sepa** del todo sobre qué quiero ser en el futuro (recae la duda sobre si sé o no sé)
> - Hacé lo que **sepas** (recae la duda sobre qué es lo que sabés)
> - Hacelo como **sepas** (recae la duda sobre cómo sabés)
> - Me gustaría que **supieras** cómo hacer esto (dudo mucho que lo sepas hacer)
> - No creo que **supiera** cómo hacer eso. (dudo sobre si, dada alguna circunstancia hipotética, supiera cómo hacer algo)
> - No creo que **quiera** ser nada en el futuro. (dudo sobre si realmente quiero ser algo, atenti al uso de ‘nada’)
> - Como **quieras** (no sé como lo que querés)
> - Lo que **quieras** (similar)
> - Me gustaría que **quisieses** ser narcotraficante (no creo que quieras serlo)

Por último, en algunas situaciones en las que predomina el asombro, la sorpresa o una ‘duda-certeza mixta’ es posible usar conjugaciones de los dos modos, pero se prefiere el subjuntivo:

> - Qué raro que **funcione/funciona** bien tu computadora
> - No me parece que se **pueda/puede** entregar este trabajo en tiempo y forma
> - Aunque no **sea/es** posible viajar a Marte hoy en día, dentro de poco podremos hacerlo

**Sobre el *que* y el *qué***

Si prestás atención casi siempre los subjuntivos van precedidos por el ‘que’ (relativo). Pero en ningún caso usé el ‘qué’ (interrogativo) seguido de un verbo en subjuntivo. En general, esta combinación no da buenos resultados.

Creo que el germen de tu pregunta reside en una mala interpretación de ‘qué’. Esa palabrita mágica no representa duda. El significado correcto de la misma sería: ‘hay algo que me falta, que *sé* que existe; y que si bien no sé qué es, lo **quiero** conocer’. Es decir, lo que se resalta es la **carencia** y el **deseo** de conocer, pero no la duda. Por eso, en general no tiene sentido usar verbos en subjuntivo a continuación de esta partícula.